# Cloud PostgreSQL clean large objects vacuumlo

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, vacuum, lob

We are managing to use GCP CloudSQL for our PostgreSQL database,
at this moment one of our applications uses large objects and i was wondering how to perform a **vacuumlo** operation on such platforms (question might be valid for AWS RDS or any other cloud postgresql provider).
Does making custom queries/procedures to perform the same task is the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vacuumlo` is a client tool, it should work just fine with hosted databases.

Comment: I checked last night that vacuumlo accepts host and port too .. my mistake, thanks